# crosstools-ng can't find pthread.so

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I am trying to use crosstools-ng to compile a program that uses pthread, however for some reason the linker can't find the library. I have checked and the libraries are located in the link path specificed by `-L` is the arguments.

Here is the error:

```
/home/***/raspberrypi/toolchain/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../.. /arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0

/home/***/raspberrypi/toolchain/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.6.3/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread_nonshared.a
```

Why can't ld find the file that is within the path?

Comment: is that file a broken symlink?

Comment: If I add a symlink from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf and /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf it compiles.  The symlinks in the directories are all relative.

Comment: /usr/lib/libpthread.so from your toolchain is a linker script. Can you post contents of this file since I don't get it why this is /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 instead of regular /lib/libpthread.so.0

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "/usr/lib/libpthread.so from your toolchain".  There is a file in that path under the toolchain rootfs.

Comment: Yes it should be have a file with this path in your toolchain sysroot.

Comment: Yup, it is there but for some reason it doesn't see it without a symlink from the system directory /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf and /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf into the sysroot directory.  This has my really confused because it picks up other libs correctly.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I'm thinking about the following file: `/home/***/raspberrypi/toolchain/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libpthread.so` (standard installation with crosstool-ng). Do you have this file?

Answer (score 7):

Edit your .../usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so:

```
/* GNU ld script
Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread_nonshared.a )
```

to

```
/* GNU ld script
Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( libpthread.so.0 libpthread_nonshared.a )
```

Comment: Thanks! I've encountered to this problem while cross-compiling a rust project. I'm still confused why this is working since the original version's paths are valid related to the sysroot.

Answer (score 2):

See this info page:
https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/ld/File-Commands.html#File-Commands

Read the definitions of INPUT and GROUP, specifically:

In case a sysroot prefix is configured, and the filename starts with the `/' character, and the script being processed was located inside the sysroot prefix, the filename will be looked for in the sysroot prefix. Otherwise, the linker will try to open the file in the current directory. If it is not found, the linker will search through the archive library search path. See the description of `-L' in Command Line Options.

So your linker script should be:

```
/* GNU ld script
Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/libpthread.so.0 /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a )
```

...as your toolchain is using a sysroot prefix.

You can find your sysroot prefix with:

```
<tuple>-gcc -print-sysroot
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the GCC `--sysroot=dir` flag should fix the issue.
This flag tells GCC to search both headers and libraries under the `dir` folder.

In your case, if you add `--sysroot=/home/user/rpi_root` to linker flags, `ld` will search for `/home/user/rpi_root/lib/libpthread.so.0` instead of just `/lib/libpthread.so.0`.

This is particularly helpful to fix linking with fullpath to library.

When using CMake to generate build system, you should use `SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${RPI_ROOT_PATH})`, where `RPI_ROOT_PATH` contains the path to the RPi sysroot instead of directly set compiler flags.